# Is it OK to recursively parse the args in a va_list?

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

Suppose I want to make a function that recursively parses a variadic argument list, by letting each invocation of the function read the next argument? After handing the va_list to the next function, I am not intending to continue using the va_list in the calling function. Is the following code ok:

```
void VarArgRecursive( va_list args ) {
    int nextArg = va_arg(args, int);
    if( nextArg != -1 ) {
        printf("Next arg %d\n", nextArg);
        VarArgRecursive(args);
    }
}

void VarArgFunc( int firstArg, ... ) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, firstArg);
    VarArgRecursive(args);
    va_end(args);
}

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {

    VarArgFunc(20, 12, 13, -1);

    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles on my system, and the output is as expected:

```
Next arg 12
Next arg 13
```

So, is this practice OK? I have searched the list, and found that after handing the va_list over to the next function, the contents of the va_list in the calling function is undefined. That shouldn't matter for my usage, as I will not continue using the va_list after handing it over to the next (well, actually, the same) function. I have also checked this page:

http://c-faq.com/varargs/handoff.html

...which shows that my way of handing over the va_list to the next function is OK. What it doesn't say, is whether it is OK to hand the va_list over to yet another function after reading one arg, and expect the called function to read the next arg. If there are c++ -specific answers to this question, that is also ok, since it will be used in a c++ program.

Comment: If you're asking about C++, tag it C++.

Comment: Using `varargs` is highly discouraged; use variadic templates, available in G++ since (IIRC) 4.5 - I use only G++, so I can't tell about other compilers, but I guess all mainstream compilers - excluding MSVC - already have support for it). But, my main point: `varargs` is evil. It's usage was discouraged for really long time and only serious usecase of it is `printf()` family.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen: I didn't tag it c++, because I thought the va_list and va_arg macros belonged to the c language, and not c++. I even contemplated on explaining this in my post. I am a c programmer who is learning c++, so I tend to do things the c way. I didn't know there was a different way of doing it in c++.

Comment: @Griwes: Thanks for your reply. I searched for variadic templates. It seems to be part of c++11? Is this properly ubiquitos now so that I can safely use it, without running into portability issues?

Comment: As I said, as lobg as you don't use Microsoft's C++ compiler, you will be able to compile it. Also, don't ever do anything "the C way" in C++; it just doesn't work.

Comment: Griwes: that's bull. It's perfectly OK to use varargs on C++, and it's part of the spec just as much as variadic templates are.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi, not everything that's part of the spec is "perfectly OK" to be used.

Comment: @Griwes: I have checked out variadic templates more now. It seems to have one thing in common with much of the canonical c++ ways of doing things: It's typesafe, has a cryptic syntax, and contains much noise code. The wiki article has an example of using it recursively, which duplicates much code. I'm on a mac, using the clang compiler. The newest version supports it, but I have an older version on my system. I'd have to upgrade my compiler, and the practice was only standardized last year. I'll pass for now.

Comment: Don't forget that a template is a template, and not a function. Sometimes you really want an actual function, and there are situations where a variadic signature is simply the most appropriate solution. This is a fine question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass it however many times you like, but you cannot "use" the va_list more than once. When consumed, the va_list may be modified and using it again is undefined behavior per the C++ spec.

If you want to use it more than once, call va_copy to clone the va_list prior to consuming it, then pass the copy.

However, in your case what you're doing is acceptable. The problem arises when you attempt to pass the va_list *from the beginning* to another function.

Comment: OK, thanks. I waited it out to see if there were any objections, but I see none, and have marked it as accepted... :)